# can't change background color of a button that's imported from react-native-paper

Tags: android, ios, react-native, button, background-color

i am new to react native following a tutorial. I noticed there is no consistency of buttons between android and iOS so i thought i'd try react-native-paper library.

however, after importing the button from react-native-paper i am having problems changing the color of the button. the color is a constant color as in the image provided [how the color looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az3Ry.png)

how can i manipulate the color? also is there a better library to use for button consistency between android and iOS ?

thanks

here is the code :

```
// import stuff
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {
  Provider as PaperProvider,
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  Button
} from 'react-native-paper';
// import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';

//create stuff

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    text: "",
    todo: []
  }
  addTodo = () => {
    var newTodo = this.state.text
    var arr = this.state.todo
    arr.push(newTodo)
    this.setState({ todo: arr, text: "" })
  }

  deleteTodo = (t) => {
    var arr = this.state.todo;
    var pos = arr.indexOf(t);
    arr.splice(pos, 1);
    this.setState({ todo: arr });


  }

  renderTodos = () => {
    return this.state.todo.map(t => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={t}>
          <Text
            style={styles.todo}
            onPress={() => { this.deleteTodo(t) }}
          >{t}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <PaperProvider>
      <View style={styles.wholeStyle}>
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.header}>Notes App</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.inputStyle}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
          <Button 
          onPress={this.addTodo}
          mode='contained'
          backgroundColor='black'
          >Todo</Button>
          {this.renderTodos()}
        </View>
      </View>
      </PaperProvider>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  wholeStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0288D1'
    // backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  viewStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 30,

  },
  inputStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 1

  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 40,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold'

  },
  todo: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white'
  }


}
//export stuff

export default App;
```

[from docs, labelStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUZvD.png)
UPDATE: thanks for the feed back, I managed to correct my code , adding a button using the property labelStyle to style the text inside the button, here is the final code , setting the button to black background and red text :

```
// import stuff
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {
  Provider as PaperProvider,
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  Button
} from 'react-native-paper';
// import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';

//create stuff

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    text: "",
    todo: []
  }
  addTodo = () => {
    var newTodo = this.state.text
    var arr = this.state.todo
    arr.push(newTodo)
    this.setState({ todo: arr, text: "" })
  }

  deleteTodo = (t) => {
    var arr = this.state.todo;
    var pos = arr.indexOf(t);
    arr.splice(pos, 1);
    this.setState({ todo: arr });


  }

  renderTodos = () => {
    return this.state.todo.map(t => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity key={t}>
          <Text
            style={styles.todo}
            onPress={() => { this.deleteTodo(t) }}
          >{t}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <PaperProvider>
        <View style={styles.wholeStyle}>
          <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.header}>Notes App</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputStyle}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
              value={this.state.text}
            />
            <Button
              onPress={this.addTodo}
              mode='contained'
              color='black'
              labelStyle={styles.button}
            >Todo</Button>
            {this.renderTodos()}
          </View>
        </View>
      </PaperProvider>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  wholeStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#0288D1'
    // backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  viewStyle: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 30,

  },
  inputStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 1

  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 40,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold'

  },
  todo: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white'
  },
  button: {
    color: 'red'
  },

}
//export stuff

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `react-native-paper` [Docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html) looks like `backgroundColor` is not a valid prop to pass.

The prop to use is just `color` so it would be:

`color:{ "black" }`

Comment: Thanks , yea I noticed it had no effect, so I am wondering , is it supposed to always have a static background color then and there is no way to change it ? It’s dark blue and that won’t fit in many themes ..

Comment: Did you try using color instead of backgroundcolor?

Comment: just tried that and it worked. the color property actually sets the background color of the button. however, now i am wondering what actually changes the text color

Comment: marking your answer as the correct answer, since it's the closest to the full answer. what i missed was the property colorLabel which can set the style for the text. now I have consistant buttons across iOS and android! thanks for your help

Comment: Didn't know you wanted to change the label color too, `react-native-paper` styling is really limited as you don't have full control over your component. Majority of things has to be done trough theming: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html

Answer (score 0):

I think according to `react-native-paper` [Docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/button.html) , You can add custom styles in the style prop. define some style object in your stylesheet and asign that object in your button.

```
<Button 
 onPress={this.addTodo}
 mode='contained'
 style={styles.mybuttonstyles}>Todo
</Button>

//In Your Styles Section, 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 mybuttonstyles:{
  backgroundColor:'black'
  // all more styles you would like
 }
```

i think this should work. in `react-native-elements` [buttons](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html), its similar. (instead of style, you should provide your style object buttonStyle for custom styles.) also make sure you create a Stylesheet and make sure to import that Stylesheet like

```
import { View, Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: your answer isn't correct, but it helped me along with aiticat to find the correct way to set the text color along with background color, your right i needed to make a style however i needed to use the property labelStyle according to the documentation, and i will now update my post accordingly, thanks